# SSRS Group Header not printing on page when only Group Footer is shown

Tags: reporting-services

This is SSRS 2012.  I have my group header displaying on each page.  It does this fine, unless the only thing on the page is the group footer.  When that happens, only the Group Footer is showing.  I need the Group Header to be shown as well.

I found several posts on getting the Group Header to repeat at the top of each page, those solutions work as long as there are some detail records on the page.  When only the group footer is on the page, I cannot get the Group Header to print.

[image: print preview]

Comment: You could add an extra row (or textbox) at the end of your group that is hidden by default, but shown when the group is empty. This is easily achievable by a simple expression.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.  What would such expression look like and how would it help to print the group header?

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but if anyone is still looking for this answer, it is in Oceans comment.

Insert a blank copy of your detail row in tablix.

The Row Visibility expression should look like this:
=Iif(RowCount("YourDataSet")=0, False, True)

RowCount() should work, but I have had more consistent results explicitly naming the dataset.